Cucumber Ruby / Selenium - unable to write to clipboard
I have some JS code that writes to the clipboard via navigator.clipboard.writeText, and I want to test it using Cucumber. The code works fine in all browsers, but when I test it with the following, there's nothing in the clipboard:
Then("the embed code should be copied to my clipboard") do
  page.driver.browser.execute_cdp("Browser.grantPermissions", origin: page.server_url, permissions: %w[clipboardReadWrite])
  clip_text = page.evaluate_async_script("navigator.clipboard.readText().then(arguments[0])")
  expect(clip_text).to eq(@content_block.document.embed_code)
end

Additionally, I see this in the JS console from Chrome:
13743:4 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': Illegal invocation

I assume this is down to the tests not running in a secure context, but my tests are running on localhost, so I'm not sure what's going on.
I've tried a couple of approaches, including setting clipboard-read and clipboard-write permissions via:
page.driver.browser.add_permission("clipboard-write", "granted")
page.driver.browser.add_permission("clipboard-read", "granted")

But I still get the same error.
Any ideas?

doesn't quite seem right to grant permissions via CDP, but assuming that it is actually working... (does reading from clipboard actually work?)  you can try a workaround for the writing using the old  document.execCommand('copy'); command.  The idea is to create a text area to put the value into and select it... then send execCommand.  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

to explain the error you are seeing, the browser did lock down reading of clipboard in particular (it was a common way to steal bitcoin methinks) Calls to the clipboard API may require that events are user-initiated, AND that the event "isTrusted", which Selenium events would not be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted
